# Detect if node is being touched by any finger

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, touch, skspritenode

So I want to call a method in my app whenever there is a touchesEnd AND node buttonX is NOT being touched. Originally I was simply going to use this code:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event    
    NSArray *touchesArray = [touches allObjects];
    UITouch *touch = (UITouch *)[touchesArray objectAtIndex:0];

    CGPoint pointTouched = [touch locationInNode:self];
    SKNode *nodeAtTouchPoint = [self nodeAtPoint:pointTouched];

    if ([nodeAtPointTouched.name isEqualToString:buttonX.name]) {
        // Call the method I want to call
    }
}
```

The issue with that is that only detects if `touchesEnded` for the "current finger" and the "current finger" isn't touching `buttonX`. If fingerA touched the button, then fingerB `touchesStarted` and `touchesEnded` (anywhere else on the screen), the method I want to call would be called even if fingerA was still touching `buttonX`.

My real question: How can I call my method on `touchesEnded` for the finger that originally pressed `buttonX`, but not call that method when `touchesEnded` is called for a finger somewhere else?

EDIT: If I could make a `BOOL` method that returns whether or not a node is being touched, and it worked "anywhere" in the object (not needing data from `touchesBegan` or `touchesEnd`) , I think that would help me solve the issue.

Comment: Your question reminds me of math class.. if all Gimps are Gomps but only some Gomps are Gimps... You already check for a node's name for a touch so you have the right code in place. What exactly is the problem you are having?

Comment: Right now I have it setup to start an action `touchesBegin` on buttonX and then stop the action when `touchesEnd` on buttonX. `touchesEnd` is called for any touch. The problem is if fingerA `touchesBegin` on buttonX, then fingerB `touchesEnd` (with or without first `touchesBegin`) somewhere else, it calls the stop action even if fingerA did not `touchesEnd` on buttonX. I want the action to start when fingerA presses buttonX and only stop the action when fingerA is no longer touching buttonX (either by `touchesMoved` or `touchesEnd`) regardless of what other fingers do in the mean time.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using -nodeAtPoint:, try using -containsPoint:

```
if ([buttonX containtsPoint:pointTouched]) {
    // Code here
}
```

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question, that's just a more efficient way to detect if the tap was on the node or not.

Comment: @Johny973 It should fix the problem that the code has. the inside of the if statement happens when touchesEnded is called but only if the touch in question is inside the frame of buttonX - it will ignore other touches.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I can see you going about this.

The first without making too many changes to your code is to create a property in your class.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong)UITouch *buttonTouch;
```

And keep track of it as you loop through all touches like the example

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for (UITouch *touch in [touches allObjects])
    {
        CGPoint pointTouched = [touch locationInNode:self];
        SKNode *nodeAtTouchPoint = [self nodeAtPoint:pointTouched];

        if ([nodeAtTouchPoint.name isEqualToString:buttonX.name] && !self.buttonTouch)
        {
            self.buttonTouch = touch;
        }
    }
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for (UITouch *touch in [touches allObjects])
    {
        CGPoint pointTouched = [touch locationInNode:self];
        SKNode *nodeAtTouchPoint = [self nodeAtPoint:pointTouched];

        if ([nodeAtTouchPoint.name isEqualToString:buttonX.name] && touch == self.buttonTouch)
        {
            self.buttonTouch = nil;
            // Call the method I want to call
        }
    }
}
```

The other option and a bit more complicated would be to subclass SKSpriteNode for your button and handle touches in there and use delegation. That is how I handle buttons in my project.

Edit

I added my ButtonSprite class to GitHub just incase you might find it useful.

https://github.com/Urthstripe29/ButtonSprite

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of the finger inside the button. A unique object is returned for each finger every time from `touchesBegan` to `touchesEnded`. So its quite simple to keep track of it.

First initialise the `userData` of `buttonX`.

```
buttonX.userData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

Then use the following `touchesBegan and touchesMoved` functions.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    NSArray *touchesArray = [touches allObjects];
    for (UITouch *touch in touchesArray)
    {
        CGPoint pointTouched = [touch locationInNode:self];
        SKNode *nodeAtTouchPoint = [self nodeAtPoint:pointTouched];

        if ([nodeAtTouchPoint.name isEqualToString:buttonX.name]) {
            buttonX.userData[@"touchPoint"] = touch;
        }
    }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSArray *touchesArray = [touches allObjects];
    for (UITouch *touch in touchesArray)
    {

        CGPoint pointTouched = [touch locationInNode:self];
        SKNode *nodeAtTouchPoint = [self nodeAtPoint:pointTouched];

        if (buttonX.userData[@"touchPoint"] == touch)
        {
            if ([buttonX.name isEqualToString:nodeAtTouchPoint.name])
            {
                NSLog(@"clicked");
            }
            [buttonX.userData removeObjectForKey:@"touchPoint"];
        }
    }

}
```